# Printing dictionary keys and values by value python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, menu

For a python class I am taking I have to create a simple menu that does a few things, one of them being print out all player's jersey numbers and ratings based on rating. When the user selects 'r' from the menu the user is supposed to be able to enter a rating and then the program will print out all jersey numbers and ratings that are equal to or greater than the entered rating from the user. I thought I had it figured out but I can't seem to get it to work. Any ideas on where I went wrong here?

```
roster = {}

for i in range(5):
    x = int(input("Enter player number (0-99): "))
    y = int(input("Enter player rating: "))
    roster[x] = y

for i in sorted(roster):
    print('Jersey number:', i, 'Player rating:', roster[i])

sel = 'z'

while sel != 'q':

    sel = input("MENU: \na - Add Player\nd - Remove Player\nu - Update 
    Player Rating\n"
            "r - Output Players Above A Rating\no - Output Roster\nq - 
    Quit\n")

    if sel == 'a':
        x = int(input("Enter player number (0-99): "))
        y = int(input("Enter player rating: "))
        roster[x] = y
    elif sel == 'o':
        for i in sorted(roster):
            print('Jersey number:', i, 'Player rating:', roster[i])
    elif sel == 'd':
        delete = int(input("Enter jersey number to be deleted: "))
        del roster[delete]
    elif sel == 'u':
        update = int(input("Enter jersey number to be updated: "))
        change = int(input("Enter new player rating: "))
        roster[update] = change
    elif sel == 'r':
        above = int(input("Enter a rating: "))
        for key, value in roster.items():
            if above >= value:
                print(key)
    elif sel == 'q':
        print("Thanks for using the program")
    else:
        continue
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
elif sel == 'r':
    above = int(input("Enter a rating: "))
    for key, value in roster.items():
        if above <= value:
            print('Jersey number: ', key, 'Player rating: ', value)
```

This fixed the code. Thanks @Doodle Dee

Answer (score 1):

The user input the value of which we print out the ratings that are higher than that. In your code, this value is known as `above`.

Hence if your code, it should be

`if value >= above:` rather than `if above >= value:`

Also, take note of indentatin, it seems to me that you want the if blocks to be inside the while loop.

Comment: the if blocks are inside the while loop, the formatting just got messed up copy and pasting it over to here

Comment: I see, i have fixed the indentation, you should see it once the edit is approved.

Answer (score 1):

your question does not really elaborate on what difficulties you are facing or how the program crashes, if it crashes at all. But one thing i have noticed is that you are printing ratings that are less than or equal to the provided rating... not above or equal to the rating.

so this

```
if above >= value:
```

should be replaced with

```
if above <= value:
```

If the issue is different from this please comment back with more explanation on what you are facing and i would be glad to help